# Function parameters in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

Is there any reason to use the "Param(  ...   )" construction inside a function definition?

My understanding is that you should use this for specifying parameters to scripts (and scriptblocks). I see a lot of examples on the web with parameters listed this way instead of just listing the parameters after the function name.

Example:

```
function Foo([string]$Bar){
   #Body of function
}
```

Or,

```
function Foo{
     Param([string]$Bar)

}
```

Comment: Maybe someone has a better answer, but I'm casting my vote as "it's entirely a matter of taste."

Comment: Found this which suggests you're right:
http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/62095-powershell-arguments-param-vs-args.html

Comment: Edited question to include scriptblocks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In V1, it really is just a preference. Using the `param` statement has traditionally been more formal, but functionally it's the same thing.

You will probably see a lot more use of PARAM in PowerShell V2 because of the ability to add attributes to parameters, similar to attributes in C#.

```
param
(
[Parameter( Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
[Alias("name")]
[String]
$path
)
```

Here you can specify the parameter attribute and a bunch of arguments to that attribute. You can also specify aliases and a number of other validation requiremets.

Keith makes a couple of great points as well. You can use the param statement to pass parameters to annonymous scriptblocks ([lambda expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) or to a PS1 script.

Answer (score 6):

param() is required to specify the parameters for a script file and for scriptblocks:

```
PS> $sb = {param($x,$y) $x + $y}
PS> &$sb 1 3
4
```

Having it also be available for traditional functions is just a consistency thing IMO.  It is nicer for advanced functions which tend to have a lot of baggage, er metadata, per parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly as a consistency measure? Always specifying parameters the same way improves readability.

Answer (score -2):

Param is a function that is used to extract the value of a form variable that is passed to your program (can be [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) or any scripting language probably that uses [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)).

For example, in an [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) form, when you use an input element (tag) and specify the type to be "text" you wil also use a parameter called "name". name is given a value, say num, and this value should be the parameter for the `param` function so that it can extract the value that the user enters in the textbox in your form.